# How to compare two object elements in a mongodb array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
{
  "customerSchemes": [
    {
      "name": "A",
      "startDate": some date in valid date format
    },
    {
      "name": "B",
      "startDate": some date in valid date format.
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to figure out all documents where scheme A started before scheme B.
Please note that the scheme Array is not in ascending order of startDate. Plan B can have an earlier date as compared to plan A.
I believe unwind operator could be of some use here but not sure how to progress with next steps.

Comment: you should store dates not as string but as `Date` object. There is really no reason for storing dates as string

Comment: @TalRofe rectified, edited the document.

Comment: You can try using the `$reduce` operator to return a boolean based upon the comparison.

Comment: How many elements (or schemes) are likely to be there in the `customerSchemes` array? What are Plan A and Plan B - are they same as the scheme A and B? Are there any other schemes other than A and B?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### aggregate():

- `$filter` to filter `name: "A"` from `customerSchemes`
- `$arrayElemAt` to get first element from filtered result from above step
- same steps like above for `name: "B"`
- `$let` to declare variables for "A" in `a` and "B" in `b`
- `in` to check condition from above variables if `a`'s `startDate` is greater than `b`'s `startDate` then return true otherwise false
- `$expr` expression match with `$eq` to match above process, if its true then return document

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          {
            $let: {
              vars: {
                a: {
                  $arrayElemAt: [
                    {
                      $filter: {
                        input: "$customerSchemes",
                        cond: { $eq: ["$$this.name", "A"] }
                      }
                    },
                    0
                  ]
                },
                b: {
                  $arrayElemAt: [
                    {
                      $filter: {
                        input: "$customerSchemes",
                        cond: { $eq: ["$$this.name", "B" ] }
                      }
                    },
                    0
                  ]
                }
              },
              in: { $gt: ["$$a.startDate", "$$b.startDate"] }
            }
          },
          true
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lunDGJXXaNQ)

---

#### find():

You can use above match stage expression condition in `find()` query as well without any aggregation pipeline,

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/w9j1hGalBp3)

> **latest support hint**: if you are using latest(4.4) MongoDB version then you can use `$first` instead of `$arrayElemAt`, see [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/K3AYU756rr-)

Comment: the answer is flexible you can use `$lt` instead of `$gt` in `in` of `$let`, there are two meanings of term *earlier*, its up to OP's requirement.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `$unwind` array and format the elements for comparison effectively transforming into key value pair. This assumes you only have two array values so I didn't know apply any filtering.

Something like

```
db.colname.aggregate(
[
  {"$unwind":"$customerSchemes"},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$_id",
    "data":{"$push":"$$ROOT"},
    "fields":{
      "$mergeObjects":{
        "$arrayToObject":[[["$customerSchemes.name","$customerSchemes.startDate"]]]
      }
    }
  }},
  {"$match":{"$expr":{"$lt":["$fields.A","$fields.B"]}}},
  {"$project":{"_id":0,"data":1}}
])
```

Working example here - https://mongoplayground.net/p/mSmAXHm0-o-

Using `$reduce`

```
db.colname.aggregate(
[
  {"$addFields":{
    "fields":{
      "$reduce":{
        "input":"$customerSchemes",
        "initialValue":{},
        "in":{
          "$mergeObjects":[
            {"$arrayToObject":[[["$$this.name","$$this.startDate"]]]},
            "$$value"]
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  {"$match":{"$expr":{"$lt":["$fields.A","$fields.B"]}}},
  {"$project":{"fields":0}}
])
```

Working example here - https://mongoplayground.net/p/WNxbScI9N9b

Answer (score 2):

So the idea is

1. Sort the `customerSchemes` array by `startDate`.
2. Pick the first item from the sorted list.
3. Include it only if the `customerSchemes.name` is `A`.

Try this query:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$customerSchemes" },
    {
        $sort: { "customerSchemes.startDate": 1 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            customerSchemes: { $push: "$customerSchemes" }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $eq: [{ $first: "$customerSchemes.name" }, "A"]
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Output:

```js
/* 1 createdAt:3/12/2021, 6:40:42 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604b685232a8d433d8ede6c4"),
    "customerSchemes" : [
        {
            "name" : "A",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2021-03-01T00:00:00.000+05:30")
        },
        {
            "name" : "B",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2021-03-02T00:00:00.000+05:30")
        }
    ]
},

/* 2 createdAt:3/12/2021, 6:40:42 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604b685232a8d433d8ede6c6"),
    "customerSchemes" : [
        {
            "name" : "A",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2021-03-01T00:00:00.000+05:30")
        },
        {
            "name" : "B",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2021-03-05T00:00:00.000+05:30")
        }
    ]
}
```

Test data:

```js
/* 1 createdAt:3/12/2021, 6:40:42 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604b685232a8d433d8ede6c4"),
    "customerSchemes" : [
        {
            "name" : "A",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2021-03-01T00:00:00.000+05:30")
        },
        {
            "name" : "B",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2021-03-02T00:00:00.000+05:30")
        }
    ]
},

/* 2 createdAt:3/12/2021, 6:40:42 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604b685232a8d433d8ede6c5"),
    "customerSchemes" : [
        {
            "name" : "A",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2021-03-03T00:00:00.000+05:30")
        },
        {
            "name" : "B",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2021-03-02T00:00:00.000+05:30")
        }
    ]
},

/* 3 createdAt:3/12/2021, 6:40:42 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604b685232a8d433d8ede6c6"),
    "customerSchemes" : [
        {
            "name" : "B",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2021-03-05T00:00:00.000+05:30")
        },
        {
            "name" : "A",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2021-03-01T00:00:00.000+05:30")
        }
    ]
}
```